# Add launcher icon to homescreen on app install (without launch) - Pre and post oreo

Tags: android, kotlin, android-8.0-oreo, android-shortcut, android-shortcutmanager

I have seen on my device running Android 10 that few apps (which are not on playstore) add their launcher icon to homescreen just after install is complete (even without launching the app. I checked that the app's process was not running when the icon got added).
I could not find any way to do it on the internet.

I know about `ShortcutManagerCompat.requestPinShortcut()` but for this the app needs to be launched and this piece of code needs to run. Also this asks the user to add instead of adding automatically.

Also, how can the same be done pre oreo.